# Seeing Differential of 2 Objects within JSONata

Tags: jsonata

I'm using JSONata, and I want to see if I can compare 2 objects to see the differences.
I can see there are functions to get a Boolean for it the 2 objects are different but I'm looking to actually get the differences between the 2 objects.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see the expected output for a pair of example objects to provide a proper solution, but speculatively you could do something like this to figure out what keys are not matching for 2 objects:

```
(
  $object_a_keys := $keys(object_a);
  $object_b_keys := $keys(object_b);

  $object_a_keys_not_matching_object_b :=
    $filter($object_a_keys, function($key) { 
      $not($key in $object_b_keys)
        or $lookup(object_a, $key) != $lookup(object_b, $key)
    });

  $object_b_keys_not_matching_object_a :=
    $filter($object_b_keys, function($key) { 
      $not($key in $object_a_keys)
        or $lookup(object_a, $key) != $lookup(object_b, $key)
    });
  
  /* keys that don't match between the two objects */
  $distinct(
    $append(
      $object_a_keys_not_matching_object_b, 
      $object_b_keys_not_matching_object_a
    )
  )
)
```

You can play with the solution here: https://stedi.link/3zEoNqC